# How to filter users based on user's profile field in ACL

Tags: 7

I am new when it comes to drupal.I am using [FlexiAccess](http://drupal.org/project/flexiaccess) for ACL. I have a long list of users and want to filter out users based on one of the user profile fields such as country_of_origin.

I am thinking to add a new combo "Country" and command button "Add Country" before "Add User" combo box to filter the users.

Should I use other modules to do that or there is a better way to accomplish that?